# Подключение к гитлабу в докере с лакольной машины по ssh

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

Установил гитлаб в докере, настроил репозиторий. На локальной машине сгенерировал закрытый и открытый ключ, открытый ключа загрузил в гитлаб, но при подключении выдает такое сообщение *root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey).* Выполняю подключение такой командой:

```
ssh con1
...
Host con1
  HostName localhost
  Port 22
  User root
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Как разобраться, как отладить в чем причина?

**UPD:** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
version: '3.7'
    services:
      gitlab:
       container_name: gitlab
       image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
       restart: always
       hostname: 'localhost'
       environment:
         GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
            external_url 'http://localhost'
           #external_url 'http://gitlab.test.my'
           # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
       ports:
         - '80:80'
         - '443:443'
         - '22:22'
       volumes:
         - '/opt/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
         - '/opt/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
         - '/opt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Результат команды `docker ps`
*c4cc01a870ae   gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   20 hours ago   Up 5 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   gitlab*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат вывода команды ssh -Tvvv git@localhost

```
# ssh -Tvvv git@localhost
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'git'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:12onE6C4aehhDbvWYUbETBhAijdT2ZeJ8EYkYmoE9Tg
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:12onE6C4aehhDbvWYUbETBhAijdT2ZeJ8EYkYmoE9Tg.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Comment: проверьте, что в конфиге sshd на сервере разрешена авторизация по ключам `AuthenticationMethods publickey ... PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Comment: `ssh -vvv` ... и смотрите лог. Должно быть `we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply`, `Server accepts key`. Или какое-то сообщение об ошибке

Comment: `HostName localhost  Port 22`... Вы точно пробросили порт с докера как `22:22`? `docker ps` в студию

Comment: И зачем вам туда доступ по ssh? Чтобы зайти внутрь контейнера, ssh не нужен. Это делается средствами докера `docker exec ...` или `docker-compose exec ...`

Comment: @user7860670 весь закомментирован, просто добавить два параметра?

Comment: @TotalPusher если ввести `ssh -vvv` отобразится, что то на подобии списка возможных команд. результат docker ps добавил в описание вопроса. ssh нужен что бы комиты гита в гитлаб отправлять

Comment: *"ssh нужен что бы комиты гита в гитлаб отправлять"* - тогда непонятно, зачем вы пытаетесь подключаться как root. Для работы с git по ssh там ничего менять не надо обычно. Как вариант, пользуйтесь https

Comment: @user7860670 а что Вас смущает в этом? root не может создать для себя репозиторий и по ssh  авторизации скидывать данные? Я не менял и не могу зайти =( Мне бы понять хотя бы в какую сторону копать

Comment: @user7860670 а можно как нибудь посмотреть логи попыток подключений?

Comment: Доступ к git идет от одноименного пользователя. Когда клон делаете gitlab даже подсказывает `git@hostname:projectname.git`

Comment: Сделайте как написано в доке, в том [шаге](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#verify-that-you-can-connect), который вы судя по всему пробуете делать, а именно `ssh -Tvvv git@localhost` и результат добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил результат работы команды

Comment: Вот видите, у вас все работает.

Comment: Тут я подскажу: На запрос вводите на клавиатуре `yes` и нажимайте Enter. Но вообще, читайте, что пишет.

Comment: Вывело `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 22: Broken pipe`

Comment: `debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:12onE6C4aehhDbvWYUbETBhAijdT2ZeJ8EYkYmoE9Tg` - судя по этому соощению, ssh работает. А не удается соединиться скорее всего потому что напутано с ключами. `identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa` - судя по этому, вы работаете от рута и пытаетесь использовать его пару ключей. `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` - а вот тут, возможно, используется другой. Сделайте `docker inspect (id контейнера с гитлабой)` и поищите секцию Mounts - в ней будет все, что подмонтировано. Ожидаю, что будет `"Source": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"`. Если нет - напутали

Comment: @TotalPusher пропустил как то Ваш комментарий, как сделаю отпишусь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для контейнера гитлаба пропишите порты 10022:22 вместо 22:22 и в ssh конфиге тоже поставьте порт 10022

Comment: Сделал не помогло, попробую все удалить и еще раз запустить

Comment: @helldrg это вам и не поможет, потому что дело не в этом. Вот если бы порт 22 был занят, то да, есть смысл переназначить на другой. Но это не ваш случай, `0.0.0.0:22->22/tcp` - значит проблем нет